# jQuery.handlebars template not rendering on dynamic DOM appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, templating-engine

I have been using dynamic DOM appending for initializing my app, using jQuery.handlebars as the templating library. But the problem with the jQuery.handlebars is that it does not render template to a dynamically invoked DOM. Example

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
         $('body').append('<div id="content"></div>');
         $('#content').render('default', {

         });
   )};
```

default is the template file default.hbs with all templates path properly initialized.

but it works in the case where

index.html

```
    <div id="#content"></div>
```

the jQuery file

```
    $('#content').render('default', {

    });
```

Another problem with jQuery.handlebars is that it does not append any element in the template using jQuery. Example

default.hbs

```
    <div id="#append-content"></div>
```

the jQuery code

```
     $('#append-content").html('Hi');
```

but content "Hi" does not appear.

It is kinda confusing, please enlighten if its wrong or if any disapproval regard usage of jQuery.handlebars, please suggest a new templating library to go with.

Comment: Do you have a failing demo in jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: @blessenm [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dhdg5c04uzrpFM5Q5UiS) this plunker tells you what it is..but first problem is partially solved in this example....appending content inside the template.hbs is a big problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery.handlebars render method is asynchronous. You are trying to append to the container before the rendering is complete. The render method triggers a 'render.handlebars' event when its done rendering. Do your DOM manipulation in a callback.

```
$('#content').render('template', {

}).on('render.handlebars', function() {
  $('#append-content').html("hello");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @blessenm, it worked like charm, btw i can't find much of docs for jquery.handlebars, can i know if you hold any references that could be shared.

Comment: I just went though the source code of the plugin. https://github.com/71104/jquery-handlebars/blob/master/src/plugin.js#L73 Its a pretty simple plugin. Do accept the answer.